# Error expected primary expression before ' - ' token

Tags: c++, function, class, struct

So I've got a structure in this called Money here the code for the struct:

```
class Money{
  private:
    unsigned int numDollars;    // number of dollars
    unsigned int numQuarters;   // number of quarters (25 cents)
    unsigned int numDimes;      // number of dimes (10 cents)
    unsigned int numNickels;    // number of nickels (5 cents)
    unsigned int numPennies;    // number of pennies (1 cents)

  public:
 // constructors for the class
 // Exercise 1 is to implement these
     Money();
     Money(unsigned int dollars, unsigned int cents);
     Money(unsigned int dd, unsigned int q, unsigned int d, unsigned int n, unsigned int p);

 // getter functions
 // these are provided for you
     unsigned int getDollars();
     unsigned int getQuarters();
     unsigned int getDimes();
     unsigned int getNickels();
     unsigned int getPennies();

 // you need to implement this getter in Exercise 2
     unsigned int getCents();

 // setter functions
 // you need to implement each of these in Exercise 2
     void addMoney(Money);
     void addDollars(unsigned int);
     void addQuarters(unsigned int);
     void addDimes(unsigned int);
     void addNickels(unsigned int);
     void addPennies(unsigned int);
     void addCents(unsigned int);

 // other methods for Exercise 3
 void leastCoins();               // Exercise 3
 unsigned int numberOfCoins();    // Exercise 3

};
```

So the code that gives me the error is when im defining my `void addMoney()` function.  It is supposed to work like this:  If I say `m1.addMoney(m2)`,
`m1` should `+= m2`, while `m2` remains the same.
I'm trying to simply add the coins from `m2` to `m1`.

```
void Money::addMoney(Money)
{
    Money::addDollars(Money.getDollars);
    Money::addQuarters(Money.getQuarters());
    Money::addDimes(Money.getDimes());
    Money::addNickels(Money.getNickels());
    Money::addPennies(Money.getPennies());
}
```

All the lines here raise that error.

Comment: Could you add the error message that you get to the post?

Answer (score 1):

Your function would look something like this

```
void Money::addMoney(Money const& other)
{
    addDollars(other.getDollars());
    addQuarters(other.getQuarters());
    addDimes(other.getDimes());
    addNickels(other.getNickels());
    addPennies(other.getPennies());
}
```

You are essentially calling each of your methods implicitly off of `this` which is a pointer to the current instance of your `Money`. Then you can call `get_` off of `other` which is the other `Money` that is passed in as an argument.